# Why shopify emails go to "all Mail" instead of "Inbox"?

Tags: email, shopify

Actually, when customer create an order he will receive an email from shopify store, lets say from LO@test.com.

for customers who have a Gmail account lets say customer1@gmail.com will receive an email from LO@test.com, customer will receive an email into "All mail" instead of "inbox", this rule apply in all customers.

but i am using  lo@test.com in other platform, when customers  receiving email will go to inbox even if customer have a gmail account, so issue only occurred if LO@test.com sent from shopify?

I talked with shopify support team but we did not find a solution yet, what did you think i need to do?

could you please check attached images?
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is actually very unusual that the emails end up under "all mail" what that means is that the email lacks labels or has ben archived, if this is an automated process, would it be possible that there are filters in place that are set to automatically archive emails(Skip the Inbox)?

You can check the filters following these steps: https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/11237244?hl=en#zippy=%2Cedit-or-delete-filters

Comment: I also noticed that you mentioned this happens to everyone, if the above answer does not solve your problem, could you please share message headers for an email that was received in the inbox and one that was not?

Comment: To get message headers you can follow these steps: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/29436?hl=en

Comment: Andre, I added a message headers, the issue for all customers, we test it with more than 6 customers have gmail account, the issue is only occurred with gmail?!

Comment: Hey Mohamad! Is there any other place where the emails show? it seems unexpected that the emails are just archived from the get go... If you happen to have someone with a Workspace account they could contact Workspace support to have a better idea

Comment: If this happens exclusively on Gmail then the only option becomes submitting a feedback through these steps: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/9212652

Answer (score 0):

You need to talk with email provider and ensure 'whitelist' the following addresses:

smtp.shopify.com

smtp2.shopify.com

smtp3.shopify.com

smtp4.shopify.com

mailer@shopify.com

This usually will solve the issue and allow your customers to receive the notifications in their inbox as you normally would.